# Write in the row under the function IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I want to write in the row under the function IMPORTRANGE but when I do that the function stop working bc it cant increase. Can someone know how to solve that pls?
here is my google sheet :

exemple: When i want to write in the row 15 column A,B,C or D  the function stop working and I have a REF ERROR but I want to be able to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IMPORTRANGE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) function occupies a range based on the data that queries. If you add some content within the datarange that importrange returns, the latter will break because it can't expand.

You can either restrict the range that importrange occupies:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("SprdID";"All Months!$A$1:$D14")
```

or add content starting from **column E**. You can also put the importrange function in bottom rows and use the top rows for manually entered data.

Since the raw data could potentially **increase** in the future, I would advice you to have a dedicated sheet to accommodate the importrange function and all of the other calculations/formulas to be stored in a different sheet.

References:

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/26662291?hl=en

Comment: I cant bc the data is going to grow so I must put " All Months!$A$1:$D" and I cant add content in the column E. My boss want to under the function IMPORTRANGE

Comment: why don't you then put the importrange at lower rows? put the formula let's say in row 50, and do your calculations before that.